# cursor <cursor name> does not exist, 34000 | Postgres

Tags: postgresql, cursor

I am trying to execute below code but I am facing error as **cursor v1_cur does not exist,34000**. Could anyone please let me know where the error is?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION data_del(
   OUT p_message_out CHARACTER VARYING,
   OUT p_sqlstate_out CHARACTER VARYING
   )
   RETURNS RECORD AS
$BODY$

DECLARE 
v_msg CHARACTER VARYING(160);
v_sqlstate CHARACTER VARYING(6);
v1_cur RECORD;
c1_cur CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM mydata WHERE event_timestamp<=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '15 Days';

BEGIN
OPEN c1_cur;
LOOP
FETCH c1_cur INTO v1_cur;
EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
DELETE FROM mydata WHERE CURRENT OF v1_cur;
END LOOP;
CLOSE c1_cur;

v_msg = 'Data deleted successfully.';
v_sqlstate = 1; 

p_message_out = v_msg;
p_sqlstate_out = v_sqlstate;


EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
p_message_out=SQLERRM;
p_sqlstate_out=SQLSTATE;

END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE SECURITY DEFINER
```

Comment: Why do you use a loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CURRENT OF` must be followed by a cursor name (`c1_cur`), not by a record.

Comment: Yes, that's working but then what's the use of v1_cur and what should we use instead of loop?

Comment: BEGIN    DELETE FROM mydata WHERE event_timestamp<=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '15 Days';    RAISE NOTICE ''Data deleted successfully.'';    END;

Comment: So are you saying that there is no need of cursor? I am using it as there may be more than 1L records in a table.

Comment: Yes I am. You want to clear out a huge amount of data from a massive table and you want to do it in batches. You can add a LIMIT clause : DELETE FROM mydata WHERE event_timestamp<=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '15 Days' LIMIT 1000000;

Comment: This batch could be run every now and then minimize load on the system.

Comment: I would put it in a cron job.